# Iterating over for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, python-2.x

I have this piece of Python code:

```
time =  ['0115','0215','0315','0715','0815','0915','1015']
N_profiles_select = 582
cldsat_timeafter = 0815
cldsat_timebefore = 0115

if time < cldsat_timeafter and time > cldsat_timebefore:  
    for i in range(N_profiles_select):  
        print time
```

Right now it prints out the first time (which is 0215), 582 times then prints the second time (which is 0315) 582 times and then the third time 582 times.

What I want it to do is to print the times in this order:

```
0215,0315,0715, 0215,0315,0715
```

That would then repeat the three numbers 582 times. How would I do that?

Comment: Python? And where is time defined, what is it?  You need to give some more info for us to be able to answer your question.

Comment: I added to my orignial question!

Comment: Why those particular times? Why not `0415` and `0615` as well? The best solution probably depends on the logic behind why you want to do this - could you clarify?

Comment: I am looping through satellite data and am taking out specific times in order to match with other data. These times come from hourly geostationary satellite data. Some of the times do not have data in them, so they get looped over anyways.

Comment: `cldsat_timeafter = 0815` gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
for i in range(N_profiles_select):
    for t in time:
        if t < cldsat_timeafter and t > cldsat_timebefore:
            print t
```

(just changed the order of the for loops)

This is just to show the logic. But you would better determine which elements of `time` you want to print once and for all, instead of testing it `N_profiles_select` times.

You would do:

```
selectedTimes = [t in time if t < cldsat_timeafter and t > cldsat_timebefore]
for i in range(N_profiles_select):
    for t in selectedTimes:
        print t
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) to avoid iterating over the list more than once:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

time =  ['0115','0215','0315','0715','0815','0915','1015']
N_profiles_select = 582
cldsat_timeafter = '0815'
cldsat_timebefore = '0115'

filtered_elements = [x for x in time if cldsat_timebefore < x < cldsat_timeafter]
for elem in chain.from_iterable(repeat(filtered_elements, N_profiles_select)):
    print elem
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives what you are asking for:

```
time =  ['0115','0215','0315','0415','0615','0715','0815','0915','1015']
N_profiles_select = 582
cldsat_timeafter = '0815'
cldsat_timebefore = '0115'

for i in range(N_profiles_select):
    for t in time:
        if t < cldsat_timeafter and t > cldsat_timebefore:
            print t
```

Prints:

```
0215
0315
0415
0615
0715
```

`N_profiles_select` times

**PS:** remember to use single quotes `'` when setting values to `cldsat_timeafter` and `cldsat_timebefore`.

Comment: I don't think it does; OP wants t printed more than once.

Comment: Sure, then add another loop, even I don't see why ;)

Comment: Quoting OP: "That would then repeat the three numbers 582 times. How would I do that? ". This is not what your answer does.